# I am getting NoReverseMatch at /blog u'posts' is not a registered namespace error after adding some functionality to my project

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a project with that consists of a main page that has a blog feature and a text editing feature. In adding the text editing feature I seem to have disrupted almost all of the functionality of the blog app. The only thing that is rendering on / is empty bootstrap modules with none of the blog content (the link also bounces back to / no as well.

/blog, which used to go to a list_view returns a NoReverseMatch at /blog
u'posts' is not a registered namespace error

as do any of the /blog/slug which went to detail views. I can still create blog posts however through the django admin.

I know I am doing something wrong and could use some help as to where I screwed this up

The directory structure is as follows
The directory stucture is as follows:

```
 - src [Folder] 
   - content [Folder]
     - migrations [Folder]
     - __init__.py
     - admin.py
     - apps.py
     - models.py
     - tests.py
     - views.py
  - main [Folder]
     - settings [Folder]
         - __init__.py
         - base.py
     - migrations [Folder]
     - __init__.py
     - db.sqlite3
     - models.py
     - urls.py
     - views.py
     - wsgi.py
  - posts [Folder]
     - migrations [Folder]
     - templatetags [Folder]
     - __init__.py
     - admin.py
     - apps.py
     - forms.py
     - models.py
     - tests.py
     - urls.py
     - utils.py
     - views.py
    - templates
     - base.html
     - blogbase.html
```

my urls.py - main is as follows

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db import models
from django.views.generic import ListView

from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from accounts.views import (login_view, register_view, logout_view)
# from main.views import MyView
from views import MyView

from posts.views import (
    home,
    post_list,
    post_create,
    post_detail,
    post_update,
    post_delete,
    )

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^comments/', include("comments.urls", namespace='comments')),

    url(r'^register/', register_view, name='register'),
    url(r'^login/', login_view, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/', logout_view, name='logout'),
    url(r'^$', MyView.as_view(template_name=('base.html')), name='name'),
    # url(r'^$', home),
    url(r'^blog$', post_list, name='list'),
    url(r'^blog/create/$', post_create),
    url(r'^blog/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', post_detail, name='detail'),
    url(r'^blog/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/edit/$', post_update, name='update'),
    url(r'^blog/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/delete/$', post_delete),


    # url(r'^', include("posts.urls", namespace='posts')),
    #url(r'^posts/$', "<appname>.views.<function_name>"),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

my urls.py - posts is as follows:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from .views import (
    home,
    post_list,
    post_create,
    post_detail,
    post_update,
    post_delete,
    )

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', home),
    url(r'^blog$', post_list, name='list'),
    url(r'^blog/create/$', post_create),
    url(r'^blog/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', post_detail, name='detail'),
    url(r'^blog/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/edit/$', post_update, name='update'),
    url(r'^blog/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/delete/$', post_delete),
    #url(r'^posts/$', "<appname>.views.<function_name>"),
]
```

my views.py - main is as follows:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.generic import View
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView, TemplateResponseMixin, ContextMixin


from posts.models import Post
from content.models import Content

class DashboardTemplateView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "base.html"
    context_object_name = 'name'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(DashboardTemplateView,self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context["title"] = "This is about us"
        return context

class MyView(ContextMixin, TemplateResponseMixin, View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data(**kwargs)
        # mission_statement = Content.objects.filter(Content.objects.title == 'test')
        # context = {'mission_statement' : mission_statement,
        #           'content_list' : Content.objects.all(),
        #           'post_list' : Post.objects.all()}
        context = {'content_list' : Content.objects.all(), 'post_list':Post.objects.all()}
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

my views.py - posts are as follows:

```
try:
    from urllib import quote_plus #python 2
except:
    pass

try:
    from urllib.parse import quote_plus #python 3
except: 
    pass

from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger

from django.db.models import Q
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect, Http404
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.utils import timezone

from comments.forms import CommentForm
from comments.models import Comment
from .forms import PostForm
from .models import Post



def post_create(request):
    if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
        raise Http404

    form = PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.user = request.user
        instance.save()
        # message success
        messages.success(request, "Successfully Created")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
    context = {
        "form": form,
    }
    return render(request, "post_form.html", context)

def post_detail(request, slug=None):
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    if instance.publish > timezone.now().date() or instance.draft:
        if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
            raise Http404
    share_string = quote_plus(instance.content)

    initial_data = {
            "content_type": instance.get_content_type,
            "object_id": instance.id
    }
    form = CommentForm(request.POST or None, initial=initial_data)
    if form.is_valid() and request.user.is_authenticated():
        c_type = form.cleaned_data.get("content_type")
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get(model=c_type)
        obj_id = form.cleaned_data.get('object_id')
        content_data = form.cleaned_data.get("content")
        parent_obj = None
        try:
            parent_id = int(request.POST.get("parent_id"))
        except:
            parent_id = None

        if parent_id:
            parent_qs = Comment.objects.filter(id=parent_id)
            if parent_qs.exists() and parent_qs.count() == 1:
                parent_obj = parent_qs.first()


        new_comment, created = Comment.objects.get_or_create(
                            user = request.user,
                            content_type= content_type,
                            object_id = obj_id,
                            content = content_data,
                            parent = parent_obj,
                        )
        return HttpResponseRedirect(new_comment.content_object.get_absolute_url())


    comments = instance.comments
    context = {
        "title": instance.title,
        "instance": instance,
        "share_string": share_string,
        "comments": comments,
        "comment_form":form,
    }
    return render(request, "post_detail.html", context)

def post_list(request):
    today = timezone.now().date()
    queryset_list = Post.objects.active() #.order_by("-timestamp")
    if request.user.is_staff or request.user.is_superuser:
        queryset_list = Post.objects.all()

    query = request.GET.get("q")
    if query:
        queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(
                Q(title__icontains=query)|
                Q(content__icontains=query)|
                Q(user__first_name__icontains=query) |
                Q(user__last_name__icontains=query)
                ).distinct()
    paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 8) # Show 25 contacts per page
    page_request_var = "page"
    page = request.GET.get(page_request_var)
    try:
        queryset = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        queryset = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
        queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)


    context = {
        "object_list": queryset, 
        "title": "List",
        "page_request_var": page_request_var,
        "today": today,
    }
    return render(request, "post_list.html", context)


def post_update(request, slug=None):
    if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
        raise Http404
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=instance)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        messages.success(request, "<a href='#'>Item</a> Saved", extra_tags='html_safe')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())

    context = {
        "title": instance.title,
        "instance": instance,
        "form":form,
    }
    return render(request, "post_form.html", context)



def post_delete(request, slug=None):
    if not request.user.is_staff or not request.user.is_superuser:
        raise Http404
    instance = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    instance.delete()
    messages.success(request, "Successfully deleted")
    return redirect("posts:list")

def home(request, slug=None):
    today = timezone.now().date()
    queryset_list = Post.objects.active()[:1] #.order_by("-timestamp")
    if request.user.is_staff or request.user.is_superuser:
        queryset_list = Post.objects.all()[:1]

    query = request.GET.get("q")
    if query:
        queryset_list = queryset_list.filter(
                Q(title__icontains=query)|
                Q(content__icontains=query)|
                Q(user__first_name__icontains=query) |
                Q(user__last_name__icontains=query)
                ).distinct()
    paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 8) # Show 25 contacts per page
    page_request_var = "page"
    page = request.GET.get(page_request_var)
    try:
        queryset = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        queryset = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
        queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)


    context = {
        "object_list": queryset, 
        "title": "List",
        "page_request_var": page_request_var,
        "today": today,
    }
    return render(request, "base.html", context)
```

my base.html is as follow:

```
{% for post in post_list %}
<div class="section" id="blog">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
                <a href="/blog"><h1>Blog</h1></a>
                <br>
                <p>Come Check out our Blog for the most up to date information on how you can best help your child!</p>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
                <div class="jumbotron">
                    <h2><a href='{{ obj.get_absolute_url }}'>{{ obj.title }}</a> <small>{{ obj.publish }}</small></h2>
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                    {% if obj.image %}
                     <img src='{{ obj.image.url }}' class='img-responsive' />
                    {% endif %}
                    </div>
                  <div class="caption post-detail-item">
                    {% if obj.draft %}<h3>Staff only: Draft</h3>{% endif %} {% if obj.publish > today %}<h3>Staff Only: Future Post</h3>{% endif %}
                    {% if obj.user.get_full_name %}<p>Author: {{ obj.user.get_full_name }}</p>{% endif %}
                    {{ obj.get_markdown|truncatechars_html:120 }}
                    <p><a href="{{ obj.get_absolute_url }}" class="btn btn-primary outline" role="button">Continue Reading</a></p>
                  </div>
                <!-- </div> -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

postlist.html - is as follows

```
{% extends "blogbase.html" %}
{% block content %}



<div class='col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3'>
    <h1>Posts</h1>
    <form method='GET' action='' class='row'>
            <div class='col-sm-6'>
                <div class='input-group'>
                    <input class='form-control' type='text' name='q' placeholder='Search posts' value='{{ request.GET.q }}'/>
                    <span class='input-group-btn'>
                        <!-- <input class='btn btn-default' type='submit' value='Search' /> -->
                        <button class='btn btn-default' type='submit'>Search <i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
    </form>
    {% for obj in object_list %}
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            {% if obj.image %}
             <img src='{{ obj.image.url }}' class='img-responsive' />
            {% endif %}
          <div class="caption post-detail-item">
            {% if obj.draft %}<h3>Staff only: Draft</h3>{% endif %} {% if obj.publish > today %}<h3>Staff Only: Future Post</h3>{% endif %}
            <h3><a href='{{ obj.get_absolute_url }}'>{{ obj.title }}</a> <small>{{ obj.publish }}</small></h3>
            {% if obj.user.get_full_name %}<p>Author: {{ obj.user.get_full_name }}</p>{% endif %}
            {{ obj.get_markdown|truncatechars_html:120 }}
            <p><a href="{{ obj.get_absolute_url }}" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">View</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    <hr/>
</div>
{% endfor %}


<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if object_list.has_previous %}
            <a href="?{{ page_request_var }}={{ object_list.previous_page_number }}{% if request.GET.q %}&q={{ request.GET.q }}{% endif %}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ object_list.number }} of {{ object_list.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if object_list.has_next %}
            <a href="?{{ page_request_var }}={{ object_list.next_page_number }}{% if request.GET.q %}&q={{ request.GET.q }}{% endif %}">next</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>

</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

models.py - posts is as follows

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe
from django.utils.text import slugify


from markdown_deux import markdown
from comments.models import Comment

from .utils import get_read_time
# Create your models here.
# MVC MODEL VIEW CONTROLLER


#Post.objects.all()
#Post.objects.create(user=user, title="Some time")

class PostManager(models.Manager):
    def active(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Post.objects.all() = super(PostManager, self).all()
        return super(PostManager, self).filter(draft=False).filter(publish__lte=timezone.now())


def upload_location(instance, filename):
    #filebase, extension = filename.split(".")
    #return "%s/%s.%s" %(instance.id, instance.id, extension)
    PostModel = instance.__class__
    new_id = PostModel.objects.order_by("id").last().id + 1
    """
    instance.__class__ gets the model Post. We must use this method because the model is defined below.
    Then create a queryset ordered by the "id"s of each object, 
    Then we get the last object in the queryset with `.last()`
    Which will give us the most recently created Model instance
    We add 1 to it, so we get what should be the same id as the the post we are creating.
    """
    return "%s/%s" %(new_id, filename)

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location, 
            null=True, 
            blank=True, 
            width_field="width_field", 
            height_field="height_field")
    height_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    width_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    content = models.TextField()
    draft = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    publish = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
    read_time =  models.IntegerField(default=0) # models.TimeField(null=True, blank=True) #assume minutes
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    objects = PostManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("posts:detail", kwargs={"slug": self.slug})

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-timestamp", "-updated"]

    def get_markdown(self):
        content = self.content
        markdown_text = markdown(content)
        return mark_safe(markdown_text)

    @property
    def comments(self):
        instance = self
        qs = Comment.objects.filter_by_instance(instance)
        return qs

    @property
    def get_content_type(self):
        instance = self
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(instance.__class__)
        return content_type


def create_slug(instance, new_slug=None):
    slug = slugify(instance.title)
    if new_slug is not None:
        slug = new_slug
    qs = Post.objects.filter(slug=slug).order_by("-id")
    exists = qs.exists()
    if exists:
        new_slug = "%s-%s" %(slug, qs.first().id)
        return create_slug(instance, new_slug=new_slug)
    return slug


def pre_save_post_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.slug:
        instance.slug = create_slug(instance)

    if instance.content:
        html_string = instance.get_markdown()
        read_time_var = get_read_time(html_string)
        instance.read_time = read_time_var


pre_save.connect(pre_save_post_receiver, sender=Post)
```

Help would be very much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Post the post_list.html

Comment: Done. Thanks for helping

Comment: Where have yougiven the delete option in the template?    Is it inside the blogbase.html? Can you show where you have used it

Comment: /blog/slug/delete deletes a post

Answer (score 3):

Indeed `posts` seems not to be a registered namespace, because instead of including `posts.urls` you've decided to copy them to your main urlconf.

Uncommenting the following line and getting rid of the duplicated URLs from your main urlconf would solve the problem with your namespace.

```
url(r'^', include("posts.urls", namespace='posts'))
```

This way, however, you would have two views mounted at `/`, so you need to decide which one is the correct one.

It's not clear from the code you have provided, but I think the problem might be occurring in `Post.get_absolute_url()` if you are calling `reverse` there to build the full URL for `Post`.

Comment: Thank you uncommenting this has indeed returned /blog, /blog/create, /blog/edit. I don't completely understand why that is the case however because from what I understood this line added that into my views.py -main :context = {'content_list' : Content.objects.all(), 'post_list':Post.objects.all()}

Would you mind explaining?

Comment: These are two separate things (if I understand your comment). You first need to mount your views in an urlconf to make them visible under a specific url. Without that, you cannot access it from a browser and you cannot use `reverse` or `url` template tag to build urls 'dynamically' - because Django does not know what they are. The context on the other hand just returns a set of variables to your template, these can have any value - for example, Querysets (as is your example). Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you so much. That definitely helps.

Comment: `post_list` offers a bit more than `MyView` - pagination and simple text search.

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at models.py - posts which I just posted and pointing me in the right direction?

Comment: If you have a different problem with `models.py`, then just add a new question explaining precisely what it is. If questions are well defined, then they are arguably more helpful for the others who experience a similar problem.

It's not evident (to me) what might be wrong with your models file.